# Problema con GoogleChrome web driver

Tags: python

he tenido un problema con googleChrome webdriver, lo he instalado y movido a la carpeta correcta después de darle permisos para que se pueda ejecutar al entrar en cualquier página me pone que la conexión no es segura a pesar de que yo puse en el codigo que navegase con https alguna idea?

```
from selenium import webdriver

class InstaBot:
    def __init__(self):
        self.driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        self.driver.get("https://instagram.com")
        sleep(2)

InstaBot()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Necesitas decirle a chromedriver que ignore esas advertencias.

```
from selenium import webdriver

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument('--ignore-certificate-errors')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=options)
```